# PHP - RethinkDB eachPOS time giving 1 hour behind after clocks went forward

Tags: php, date, time, rethinkdb

So the clocks went back over the weekend..my code was working perfectly.

My issue is that due to the clocks going forward, the server seems to display for example 1 hour ago, when it was created in fact a few seconds ago...

I don't have a clue what this issue is... if it's rethinkdb or what?

Does anyone have any ideas as to why it inserts the date 1 hour behind?

Like I said, it did this on its own and was working fine...

At the moment, I've made a temporary time to +1 hour to the time in the database but this is not going to be good for long term...

To insert my times, I'm doing this:

```
$newsArray = array(
  'addressCreated' => $address,
  'orderNumber' => $orderNumber,
  'btc_amount' =>  $price,
  'email' =>  _post('email'),
  'productId' =>  $id,
  'productName' =>  $title,
  'status' =>  'awaiting_payment', // awaiting_payment | pending | paid
  'dateCreated' => \r\epochTime((int)time())
);

\r\table("orders")->insert($newsArray)->run($this->conn);
```

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved

Comment: @NicoHaase I just added the code I'm using when inserting data into the database

Comment: Do you have your server / database / PHP _time zone_ specified correctly to begin with?

Comment: @CBroe yes, all is correct on server configuration. 
Like I said, it was working fine.... then I came back to the site and now it shows 1 hour behind on all dates, even when I insert new ones.

Comment: Can you show us the actual database record and the php script you want to output it with?